# Are there security concerns in passing sensitive data through a module's function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

I recently learned about [using named parameters for memoizing in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects). I had no idea this was possible - I don't intend for my code to memoize anything. I'm not good enough at Python to understand what's going on in memory when I run my app, and I'm not even sure what questions I should ask!

My two-file app (secrets_mgmt.py and class_app.py) is structured as below (run as user `zeebrow`):

```
# secrets_mgmt.py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.Read('my_diary.txt')    # 0600 zeebrow zeebrow /home/zeebrow/.myapp.secrets

def get_secrets():
    d = {}
    d['secret_1'] = config['section']['secret_1']
    d['secret_2'] = config['section']['secret_2']
    return d
```

I pass the sensitive data to a class, like this:

```
#class_app.py
from TPL import XYZ
from secrets_mgmt import get_secrets

class app(XYZ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.secrets = {}
        self.secrets['s1'] = secrets_mgmt.get_secrets()['secret_1']
        self.secrets['s2'] = secrets_mgmt.get_secrets()['secret_2']
        super().__init__(**self.secrets)
        del secrets
```

I'm probably missing more than I realize, but from what I could think to ask:

- Are the values in self.secrets stored *anywhere*, even after I deleted them?
- Is there anything specific I should check in the third-party library's `XYZ` class to make sure it handles sensitive info correctly? It uses `requests`.
- I admit I'm blindly trusting `configparser` because it's a part of the standard library - Is this safe to do?

Comment: `self.secrets` is stored in memory and is removed from memory (to over-simplify) when the class falls out of scope; or out of the stack frame. As for the latter two question; read the docs ... carefully.

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks for your answer and pointers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting familiar with SO's input format, accidentally hit enter above.

>self.secrets is stored in memory and is removed from memory (to over-simplify) when the class falls out of scope 

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like the challenge is to keep secrets out of memory. I'm going to look into encrypting them at rest and requiring a password to start the app, or maybe some sort of class-wrapper for the secrets, destroying the class and calling the GC as soon as they're no longer needed.